# Auth Token - Can we extend the expiry period?

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication

The auth token used for triggered sends (generated via this URL https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken) expires after 60 minutes.  Is it possible to change the expiry period?  We'd like to extend...or perhaps set it to an indefinite expiry period.

Are there any options to change this expiry period?

Comment: This can not be changed. And oauth 2.0 is set to twenty minutes

Answer (score 1):

Access Token for Server-to-Server Integrations using Oauth2.0 lasts for 20 Minutes only and can't be extended. your API app has to request new one every 20 minutes. See the [Developer Docs](http://Access%20Token%20for%20Server-to-Server%20Integrations) for more information